# How to append one observable to another?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, observable

I want to initialize 12 users in my list `${this.url}/users?offset=${offset}&limit=12` but with scrolling this offset should increase by 8 users.

I want to use infinite scrolling for that. My problem is that I'm using `observables(userList)` and I don't know how to append the new list of 8 members to the old one. In the tutorials in the internet the all use `concat()` but this is for arrays:/ I myself tried something to just call the whole list + 8 offset when loadMore is true but that somehow doesn't work.

My Code:

service.ts

```
  // get a list of users
  getList(offset= 0): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/users?offset=${offset}&limit=12`);
  }
```

page.ts

```
@ViewChild(IonInfiniteScroll) infiniteScroll: IonInfiniteScroll;
userList: Observable<any>;
offset = 0;
...
 getAllUsers(loadMore = false, event?) {
    if (loadMore) {
      this.userList = this.userService.getList(this.offset += 8) //new 8 users
    .pipe(map(response => response.results));
    }
    this.userList = this.userService.getList(this.offset) // initials 12 users
    .pipe(map(response => response.results));
    if (event) {
      event.target.complete();
      console.log(event);
      console.log(loadMore);
    }
  }
```

page.html

```
...
  </ion-item>


    </ion-list>
    <ion-infinite-scroll threshold="100px" (ionInfinite)="getAllUsers(true, $event)">
        <ion-infinite-scroll-content
          loadingSpinner="crescing"
          loadingText="Loading more data...">
        </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
      </ion-infinite-scroll>

</ion-slide>

<ion-slide>
```

Comment: Use `scan` operator. It works as a reducer but also emits values after each value emit (doesn't wait for observable to complete)

Comment: @Sergey Could you maybe write it into my code as an answer? I really would know how to apply it nor what would be left over from my function I have written.

Answer (score 2):

use [Merge](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/merge.html) to merge multiple `observables` into a single observable:

```
getAllUsers(loadMore = false, event?) {
    if (loadMore) {
      const newUserList$ = this.userService.getList(this.offset += 8) //new 8 users
    .pipe(map(response => response.results));
    this.userList = merge(this.userList, newUserList$); // merge observables

    }
    this.userList = this.userService.getList(this.offset) // initials 12 users
    .pipe(map(response => response.results));
    if (event) {
      event.target.complete();
      console.log(event);
      console.log(loadMore);
    }
  }
```

## Update

From your URL maybe you should remove the limit parameter :

```
  getList(offset= 0): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/users?offset=${offset}`);
  }
```

Comment: my list does still not load more users :/ when scrolling downwards.Is there some other mistake in my code. I have really no idea what I can try further

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers, this is a good use-case for the `scan` operator.

However, we must find a way to keep adding(accumulating) data when the user scrolls. I think this can be achieved by using a `BehaviorSubject`  that will emit values on each scroll. 
I opted for this type of subject because you will want to provide an initial value as well.

```js
const loadUsersSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(12);
let userList$/* : Observable<any>; */ // Uncomment this if used inside the template along with the async pipe
let internalCnt = 0;

const generateUsers = (n: number) => {
  return of(
    Array.from({ length: n }, ((_, i) => ({ user: `user${++internalCnt}` })))
  );
}

userList$ = loadUsersSubject
  .pipe(
    flatMap(numOfUsers => generateUsers(numOfUsers)),
    scan((acc, crt) => [...acc, ...crt])
  )
  .subscribe(console.log)


// Scrolling after 1s..
timer(1000)
  .subscribe(() => {
    loadUsersSubject.next(8);
  });


// Scrolling after 3s..
timer(3000)
  .subscribe(() => {
    loadUsersSubject.next(8);
  });
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rx-playground)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how `scan` operator can be used to have a state that is augmented by following requests

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-h91d9u?devtoolsheight=60

```
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';


const source = new Observable((observer) => {
  observer.next(['Hello', 'World']);

  setTimeout(() => {
    observer.next(['will', 'concatenate']);
  }, 1000)

   setTimeout(() => {
    observer.next(['also', 'will', 'concatenate']);
  }, 2000)
}).pipe(
    scan(
      (acc, val) => acc.concat(val),
      []
    )
);

source.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```